# Does average length of sidereal day change if earths axis is tilted in different way

Tags: astronomy

Can precession of axis of rotation of earth cause change in average sidereal day length?

Comment: The precise details of Earth's rotation are quite complex. Please see  https://www.iers.org/IERS/EN/Science/EarthRotation/EarthRotation.html

Answer (score 1):

A sidereal day is the time it takes the Earth to rotate a full $360^o$. In a first approximation, this will not change if you change the tilt of the Earth.

By contrast, an ordinary day is the time between noon and noon. That is different from a sidereal day because the Earth travels some distance in its orbit over the course of a day. The direction toward the Sun has changed a bit.

Of course, it isn't that simple. Astronomers are interested in sidereal days because they are interested in the precise direction to stars. As @PM2Ring says, precise details of Earth's rotation are complex. The Sun and Moon exert torques on the Earth. Distribution of water varies with time, and this measurably changes the moment of inertia of the earth.  Please see https://www.iers.org/IERS/EN/Science/EarthRotation/EarthRotation.html.