# Is Each Day the Same Duration?

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion

Since Earth's orbit is elliptical surely each day does not have the same duration. My understanding is that at the perigee the Earth would have to rotate more than at the apogee due to its larger tangential velocity with respect to the Sun.

My question is prompted by the idea of a siderial Day which I imagine IS a constant value since in that case assuming a constant rotational speed of the Earth the angle through which the earth has to rotate is a constant 360 degrees?

Comment: Similar - [Does average length of sidereal day change if earths axis is tilted in different way](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/790107/37364)

Comment: What precision do you have in mind? Major earthquakes change Earth's moment of inertia, which can change the length of the day by milliseconds. Over geological timescales, angular momentum has moved from the Earth's rotation to the Earth-Moon orbit. [In principle, smaller variations occur as well](https://xkcd.com/162/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the solar day length varies from 24 hours - ~22 seconds to 24 hours + ~30 seconds. Here's a graph for 2022, computed for apparent solar noon at Greenwich, using data from JPL [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/)

[image: Solar day length delta]

The difference of apparent solar time minus mean solar time is known as [The Equation of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time). I have further details in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/469884/123208).

---

The sidereal day length is *fairly* constant. The precise details of Earth's rotation are quite complex. The Earth's rotation is monitored by the IERS, the [International Earth Rotation and Reference Systems Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Earth_Rotation_and_Reference_Systems_Service). There are various articles on this topic on the [IERS website](https://www.iers.org/IERS/EN/Science/EarthRotation/EarthRotation.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the length of the day varies.

This is graphically captured in the analemma, which I will display w/o explanation (other than the photo of the sun is taken at the same local time throughout the year):
[image]
[image]

Such things are captured locally in what is called "The Equation of Time", which includes Daylight Savings Time / Standard Time Differences:

[image]

The actual calculation as a function of latitude, longitude, and date is *involved*.

A good place to investigate such things is, for example:

https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/usa/pasadena-ca

Comment: Surely the analemma is a feature of the solar day? The question appears to ask about the sidereal day.

Comment: yeah, OP watched Veritasium's new wijeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUHkTs-Ipfg ...so the question left over is: does the Lense Thirring effect depend on orbital radius, and do the earth need an axis tilt (which is has) relative to the orbital plane for it to matter?